# Scala recursive types

Tags: scala, types

I'm just trying to get my head around Scala's type system. I stumbled upon a code that looks like this:

```
trait A extends Something {
  type X <: XLike

  trait XLike { this: X =>
    ....
    ....
  }
}
```

What would this mean? Under which situations would I want to code like this? I know that I'm nesting types, but what is the advantage of nesting types like this and using this to refer to the nested type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This `A#XLike` trait cannot be mixed anywhere inside `A`:

```
val a = new A {}; import a._

scala> class KK extends XLike
<console>:21: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type KK does not conform to a.XLike's selftype a.X
       class KK extends XLike
                        ^
```

It can be mixed inside `A`s implementations:

```
trait B extends A {
    type X = XImpl      
    trait XImpl extends XLike { this: X => }
}

val b = new B {}; import b._

scala> class KK extends XImpl
defined class KK
```

Or even:

```
trait B extends A {type X = XLike}

val b = new B {}; import b._

scala> class KK extends XLike
defined class KK
```

So it allows you to choose which trait is mandatory to mix-in:

```
trait B extends A {
  type X = XImpl1      
  trait XImpl1 extends XLike { this: X => }
  trait XImpl2 extends XLike { this: X => }
}

val b = new B {}; import b._

scala> class ZZ extends XImpl1
defined class ZZ

scala> class ZZ extends XImpl2
<console>:40: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type ZZ does not conform to b.XImpl2's selftype b.XImpl2 with b.X
       class ZZ extends XImpl2
                        ^
scala> class ZZ extends XImpl1 with XImpl2 // XImpl2 still can be mixed but only if XImpl1 present in linearization
defined class ZZ
```

Even several ones:

```
trait A {
   type X1 <: XLike
   type X2 <: XLike

   trait XLike { this: X1 with X2 => }
} 

trait B extends A {
    type X1 = XImpl1  
    type X2 = XImpl2

    trait XImpl1 extends XLike { this: X1 with X2 => }
    trait XImpl2 extends XLike { this: X1 with X2 => }
    trait XImpl3 extends XLike { this: X1 with X2 => }
}
```

In practice, `X1` and `X2` might have some significant roles. For instance,  if you do chain of resposibilty ([stackable traits](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html)) - you may mix-in many traits (and not all of them explicitly - there might be groups of traits) in any order, so it's good to have ability to specify one or several mandatory handlers (just to not forget them), like:

```
 val a = new Logic with Hanler with Group0
 trait Group0 extends MandatoryHandler1 with Group1 with H2
 trait Group1 extends H3 with H4 with MandatoryHandler2
 trait Group2 extends H2 with H5
```

If you change `Group0` to `Group2` you may loose your `MandatoryHandler2` (it may be some reporter for example).

Another one: library developer may provide many traits to be concise with [Single Resposibilty / Interface Segregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principle, but some of them should always be mixed in (together) by users who will play with this LEGO.

So here is classic [OOP-composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) over aggregation way (instances required):

```
 abstract class B {
    val helper1: H1 //mandatory, exactly H1, not some H
    val helper2: H2 
 }

 class C extends B {
    val helper1 = new H1 //mandatory, exactly H1, not some H
    val helper2 = new H2 
 }
 class H1 extends H {...} 
 class H2 extends H {...}
```

vs [mix-in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) way:

```
 trait B extends A {
   type helper1 = H1
   type helper2 = H2

   trait H1 extends H // no abstract members here just mix-in
   trait H2 extends H
 }

 trait C extends H1 with H2
```

Comment: What might be the possible use cases? Why would I need to do all this drama?

Comment: "I stumbled upon a code that looks like this" - how about this one. Don't worry, no drama here as the code is very simple - you're just saying that one trait should be always mixed with another one - it's just additional compile-time check.

Comment: For instance, when you do chain of resposibilty - you may mix-in over9000 traits, so it's good to have ability to specify one or several mandatory handlers , like `val a = new Logic with Hanler with OtherHandlerList; trait OtherHandlerList extends MandatoryHandler with H1 with H2` - and this is just first that came in mind.

Comment: @user3102968 added more examples to the answer